# Will the new VS2010 Beta 1 have a Virtual PC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, beta

I love the idea of using VS2010.  I downloaded it today to play with it.  But I am hesitant to install it all on my machine as upgrading from Microsoft betas is usually difficult.  Also, I am not a TFS install expert, so I don't know the best ways to set that up.

But I still want to play with it...

Does anyone know of a VPC that has it all set up and ready to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VPC only for alpha version of Visual Studio, I think.

Best way how play with VS is install into virtual machine (VmWare or VirtualPC) or install another your machine (home pc, notebook, second pc, etc...), imho.

If you haven't licence OS for virtual machine, you can try trial version of Microsoft systems or betas (Win7 and Server 2008 R2).

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft is doing allot of interesting work internally with virtualization and shipping several major virtualization products soon. [HyperV](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv-main.aspx) and [XP being virtualized in Windows 7](http://community.winsupersite.com/blogs/paul/archive/2009/04/24/secret-no-more-revealing-virtual-windows-xp-for-windows-7.aspx) most notably. It would be shocked if we didn't see this functionality in the new VS.

If you are interested in desktop virtualization for development testing check out [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) from Sun it is amazing and unlike the other high quality virtualization environments free and [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html). I use a [portable version of VirtualBox](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=15639&start=0) to drag my virtual desktops back and forth to work each day on a external SATA drive.

[link text](http://blogs.virtualizationadmin.com/conger/2009/04/30/how-microsoft-uses-hardware-virtualization-internally/)